# How to add numbers in a list with both numbers and strings

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have a list as follows:

```
ExampleList = [2,4,7,4,2,"randomword",23,42,2,1,4,-53,"newrandomword",32,5,2,3]
```

How do I add just the numbers?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following generator expression, which will add all `ints` in the list:

```
l = [2,4,7,4,2,"randomword",23,42,2,1,4,-53,"newrandomword",32,5,2,3]

sum(i for i in l if isinstance(i,int))
# 80
```

Answer (score 2):

This will take care of all the numbers :)

```
>>> import numbers
>>> x
[2, 4, 7, 4, 2, 'randomword', 23, 42, 2, 1, 4, -53, 'newrandomword', 32, 5, 2, 3, 1.02]
>>> sum(y for y in x if isinstance(y, numbers.Number))
81.02
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function `filter()`:

```
l = [2,4,7,4,2,"randomword",23,42,2,1,4,-53,"newrandomword",32,5,2,3]

sum(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), l))
# 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically You can sum up as below:

```
l = [2,4,7,4,2,"randomword",23,42,2,1,4,-53,"newrandomword",32,5,2,3]
s=0
for i in l:
    try:
        s+=int(i)
    except ValueError:
        print('not a rumber')

print('sum of number is:',s)
```